# DateTimeField displaying a textbox instead of a date picker

Tags: python, django, django-models

***The current date is being displayed but it is displayed in a textbox. How do i get a datepicker????***

> models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

> forms.py

```
class MyCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'notes', 'date']
```

> views.py

```
def add_model(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyCommentForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
            model_instance.save()
            # return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = MyCommentForm()
        return render(request, "form/my_template.html", {
            'form': form,
        })
```

> my_template.html
>   To render the form elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Displayed where? How are you rendering this in the template? Have you included any code to show a datepicker?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have added my view now.

Comment: Thanks, but we need to see the template.

Comment: Just added the template

Comment: @DanielRoseman, What am i doing wrong here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: you're just letting Django render the field as-is in the template.

Django itself doesn't provide a date-picker widget, and as you've found the 'widget' used by Django to represent a DateTimeField is a simple text field.

To have this render with a datepicker widget, you have a three options:
(jump straight to the 3rd if you just want a solution)

#### Pass a `type` of `datetime-local` to the widget inbuilt Django widget

(Not the recommended approach)

You can pass a `type` to the widget in order to have it provide a specific field type rendered in the browser.
e.g

```
from django.forms.widgets import DateTimeWidget

class MyCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'notes', 'date']
        widgets = {
            'date': DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
        }
```

This will cause the field to have the `datetime-local` type and *some* browsers will render a widget for entering date and time.

An important note when doing this is that the date format for the `value` of the field (as it will be rendered in the template) is important. It must be RFC 3339-formatted (e.g. 2001-10-08T22:47:31-07:00 - there is an RFC 3339 package in PyPI at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rfc3339/)

#### Use a client-side datetime picker

Browser support for native datetime widgets is poor and getting the output of Django to match the required value for the `datetime-local` field is annoying.
Fortunately, there are quite a few javascript libraries out there for providing date pickers (bootstrap has one, there are things like [Flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/examples/))

#### Use a Django addon that includes a date widget

There are addons (such as [django-datetime-widget](https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget) and [django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker](https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker)) that allow you to add a widget *in the Django form* using a Python class, and then that will render a Javascript-based widget in the client side.

If you can find an addon that you're happy with (i.e. it provides a date/time picker you like) then this is certainly the option I would recommend - mainly because the addon *should* take care of making sure the output from Django is in a format that the Javascript-based picker can handle, and the result in the field is something Django can handle.

I should note: I haven't personally used any of these date-time pickers.

Comment: The date issue is solved but the form is not getting saved to the DB

Comment: What did you end up doing? Using one of the datetime picker django addons?

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer. I still have issue as Adi, type added the datetimepicker form BUT it does not save to DB... so is not a solution.

Comment: @AlexWinkler can you post your model and model form? Did the model/model form save before any changes to  the date picker widget? Are you getting any errors from the server when the form is submitted?

Comment: Yes, everything worked/saved fine before I added the type: datetime-local attr. Not seeing any errors pop up. Posted this question yesterday here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128838/django-datetimeinput-type-datetime-local-not-saving-to-database