# Django DateTimeInput Type 'datetime-local' Not Saving To Database

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-forms, datetimepicker

I'm working on a django app to document trades. All the trade documentation is done on one page with an inline formset that shows all the entries and exits for a trade. All work well up to the datetimeinput field. If I remove the 'type' the form works great but is very non-user friendly.

Working entries with no 'type'
[image: https://i.imgur.com/wvmD2ux.png]

Non-working entries with 'type': 'datetime-local'
[image: https://i.imgur.com/3DtbiUZ.png]

So I guess you could say there are several issues datetime-local creates, or maybe it's not datetime-local to blame. I've been stuck on it all day and I'm really not sure where the issue comes from:

1. Entry.date value is not populated into field anymore
2. When a new date and time is selected in datetimepicker it doesn't save
3. datetime-local removes the seconds, we need the seconds

models.py

```
from django.db.models.functions import datetime

class Entry(models.Model):
    ENTRY = 'entry'
    EXIT = 'exit'

    ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (ENTRY, 'Entry'),
        (EXIT, 'Exit'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"

    trade = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    fee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    entry_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES, default=ENTRY)
```

forms.py

```
class EntriesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'datetime-local', 'class':'form-control'}),
        }

EntriesFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Trade, Entry, form=EntriesForm, extra=1)
```

views.py

```
class TradeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Trade
    form_class = CreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('trade-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(TradeUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['entries'] = EntriesFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['entries'] = EntriesFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        context = self.get_context_data()
        entries = context['entries']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if entries.is_valid():
                entries.instance = self.object
                entries.save()
        return super(TradeUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

trade_form.html

```
{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
    <h2>New Trade</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <table class="table">
                {{ entries.management_form }}

                {% for form in entries.forms %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                </thead>
                {% endif %}
                <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                        {{ hidden }}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/> <a href="{% url 'trade-list' %}">back to the list</a>
        </form>
    </div>


</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'add entry',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        prefix: 'entry_set'
    });

</script>


{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format that is submitted by a field with `type=datetime-local` appears not to be one that is accepted by Django, which in my local tests caused the form not to save. It is potentially possible to add datetime formats for fields to those that django accepts using `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` in the settings file (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS). However, if you are using localisation (i.e. `USE_L10N = True` in your settings) then DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS appears not be used (based on my tests - I haven't reviewed the underlying code). In the (admittedly limited) time I spent, I could not get DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS to have any effect at all.

Given the very limited support for `datetime-local` and difficulties getting django to accept the result in any case, I would suggest you consider using a datetime widget that gives you more control and greater cross-browser compatibility. One that appears (as of Feb 2020) to be maintained and have very limited dependencies is Flatpickr (https://flatpickr.js.org/).

In your case, to use Flatpickr you would need to include in top of the relevant HTML files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>


<script>
    // This code activates flatpickr on fields with the 'datetimefield' class when the document has loaded
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        flatpickr(".datetimefield", {
            enableTime: true,
            enableSeconds: true,
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",
        });
    });
</script>
```

and change:

```
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'datetime-local', 'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

to

```
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', attrs={'class':'datetimefield'}),
        }
```

This will cause the django-generated field to have the format that is also configured for flatpickr (which is based on the text in your fields above, and one django accepts).

There are a number of other date picker widgets you could use, and as you're already using jquery, having a jquery dependency would not necessary be a big problem for you.

Comment: Thanks SimeonJM! the flatpickr package def solved the issue. I wasn't aware that datetime-local and django had issues. At first, I installed the package pip and followed their docs but didn't work. Then I tried your script solution and it worked. Not totally sure why yet. One thing I'm still having issues with is getting new rows to showing the flatpickr widget. Currently, it's only working for rows/objects already existing. Is there a reason that the datetimefield is a class and not a type?

Comment: Realized in my last comment I didn't really highlight the fact that the new entries/rows after clicking "add entry" did not show the datetimeinput widget. I believe this may be a script issue. is there something you'd recommend for that? Been trying this answer but no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719063/when-adding-a-new-inline-to-my-formset-my-datepickers-stop-working

Comment: @AlexWinkler the reason a class is used is because the first argument to flatpickr '.datetimefield' means 'add flatpickr to all fields with class of datetimefield'.

Comment: @AlexWinkler If you add additional fields you will need to run 'flatpickr' again for the new field. If you create the field with a known id, you can run flatpickr("#id-of-new-field", {...})  (where...  Is the arguments from the original example). (I'm on phone so hopefully didn't miss anything).

Comment: almost but here's an image to show a bit more my issue https://i.imgur.com/FKQC1iu.png - basically when I click "add entry" the new entry row no longer has the datetimepicker widget. Which is odd because it has the right class. The +1 field represents the django form auto-added additional field. Which seems to work fine. It's only the fields that are added after.

Comment: @AlexWinkler to turn new added fields into date pickers, `flatpickr` needs to be run again after the new fields are added. Where you are setting up `django-formset` you can include `"added": function(){flatpickr(".datetimefield", {
            enableTime: true,
            enableSeconds: true,
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",
        });},` in the JS object and that function will run after each new row is added. That should then add the widget to the new field. (Better would be to move the flatpickr initialisation to a function, and use in the `DOMContentLoaded` handler  and `added`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment SimeonJM, I feel like I'm getting closer. Been messing with this for quite some time but still have not cracked the code. Here's another question I made regarding this topic and I specifically added your suggestings under "Updated trade_form.html scripts but with still no luck."  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185270/django-datetimefield-not-showing-datetimepicker-widget-for-new-inline-form-rows (maybe it's obvious to you what is still wrong in my code?)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late but I had a similar issue, I'm using a modelform, and Django sets an invalid date time value (at least for Chrome) in the html form elements. See if yours is also doing the same - view source.

Solution is to set the date format so that there's a T inserted between the date & time component in the html element:

```
widgets = {
  # NOTE the form element needs "2021-01-01T12:00:00" BUT by default it's like: "2021-01-01 12:00:00"
  'start_time': DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}), 
  'end_time': DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
}
```

BTW it is now recommended to use `datetime-local` and not `datetime` (deprecated) : [mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)